# Clicking the submit button is unable to fetch data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a search form where I have to fetch search results based on Customer Name, Mobile Number, Check-in Date & Check-out Date. However, the Name and Mobile No. requires text field. Also, the Check-in & Check-out date has text field but I am using jquery datepicker function for that field.

**Note:** The first text field is for Name & Number and second is for check-in & check-out date. First field is shown by default and second one is hidden by Jquery Code. The Second field is for displaying date calendar.

**HTML Code:**

```
<form method="POST" action="searched_page.php">
        <div class="input-gpfrm input-gpfrm-lg">
            <select id="srch-form" name="srch-option" required="">
                <option value="">Search by</option>
                <option value="name">Customer Name</option>
                <option value="mobile_no">Mobile Number</option>
                <option value="arrival_dt">Check-in date</option>
                <option value="departure_dt">Check-out date</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-gpfrm input-gpfrm-lg">
            <input type="text" id="dtls" name="querystr" placeholder="Search by Details" required>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker5" name="querystr" placeholder="Search by Date" required>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
    </form>
```

Date Picker JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showDays() 
  {

  }   

$("#datepicker5").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: showDays
});

</script>
```

So (considering following Jquery Code), when selecting Name & Mobile No. option (from dropdown), text field for date will hide and the one for Name & Number will show and text field for date will show and the one for Name & Number will hide when selecting check-in & check-out date option.

Jquery Code for hiding and showing text field

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#datepicker5').hide(); 
            $('#srch-form').change(function()
            {
                if($('#srch-form').val() == 'arrival_dt' || $('#srch-form').val() == 'departure_dt') 
                {
                    $('#datepicker5').show();
                    $('#dtls').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#datepicker5').hide();
                    $('#dtls').show();
                } 
            });
        });
</script>
```

Now, my query is that all of the above stuffs working well except that the search button is not working. When I select check-in date & check-out date from option first text field hideand vice-versa for Name & Number field as of above Jquery code comes in action. But, when I click the submit button, the button is unable to execute the code which is written in PHP. Means, my search results doesn't appears. I tried removing the Jquery Code and it works fine. So, I think it may be a silly mistake but any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both text input fields have the `required` attribute.  Unless both fields have been completed the form will not post.

You can use jQuery [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) or [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to add or remove the `required` property.  The snippet below removes the `required` attribute from the hidden field using jquery `prop`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker5').hide(); 
  $('#srch-form').change(function()
  {
    if($('#srch-form').val() == 'arrival_dt' || $('#srch-form').val() == 'departure_dt') 
    {
      $('#datepicker5').prop('required', true).show();
      $('#dtls').prop('required', false).hide(); // remove required
    } else {
      $('#datepicker5').prop('required', false).hide();  // remove required
      $('#dtls').prop('required', true).show();
    } 
  });
  
  // below code is here to demonstrate the form has posted but should be removed from your code
  $('form').submit(function(){ alert("form has been posted"); return false; });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="searched_page.php">
        <div class="input-gpfrm input-gpfrm-lg">
            <select id="srch-form" name="srch-option" required="">
                <option value="">Search by</option>
                <option value="name">Customer Name</option>
                <option value="mobile_no">Mobile Number</option>
                <option value="arrival_dt">Check-in date</option>
                <option value="departure_dt">Check-out date</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-gpfrm input-gpfrm-lg">
            <input type="text" id="dtls" name="querystr" placeholder="Search by Details" required>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker5" name="querystr" placeholder="Search by Date" required>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
    </form>
```

**Note** you should remove the code that alerts when the form is submitted, that is just to demonstrate that the form is posted successfully.

Comment: thanks for your response as it solve my query. But further, now the same code is blocking my PHP code to execute.

Comment: Please refer PHP code: if(isset($_POST['search'])){$srchOption = $_POST['srch-option'];$srchData = $_POST['querystr'];}.Both of the text field contain name attribute as "querystr" & it's displaying all records from database instead of specific search record, Refer: $searchData=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `personal_data` WHERE `$srchOption` LIKE '%$srchData%'"); Means, $_POST['querystr'] is getting the value of active text field as well as empty string from another text field which we hide & set to not required.

Comment: Set the `disabled` property of the textbox when the dropdown changed.  Something like `$('#dtls').prop({'required': false, `disabled`: true}).hide();` should work.